# align font-awesome icon in the middle

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

Im using font awesome icons. Somehow i cant seem to get them in vertically aligned in the middle.

The white part has to be in the middle of the black part. I made a pen using codepen. https://codepen.io/kevin-bobsen/pen/qKZKRX
I tried:

```
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
```

still not working.

Comment: You could easily do that by adding a `line-height` to your icons. `#icons i {line-height: 30px;}` `30px` being the height of your div `#icons`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height` to your **#icons id**:

```
#icons i {

  line-height: 30px;

}
```

Comment: I guess its not a best idea to use line height because sometimes if we have a dynamic content and a height is greater than above mention then the icons are not going to align vertically centered.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use align-items:center with display:inline-flex for your solution like i did in following code. Please have a look

```css
#main {
height:400px;
width:600px;
border:1px solid black;
margin:0 auto;
}
#pic{
width:300px;
height:100%;
float:left;
}

#bio{
width:300px;
height:100%;
float:right;
background:grey;
}

#avatar{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-top:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#avatar img{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;

  border-radius:360px;
}

#avatar span{
  font-size:18px;
  margin-left:30px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:15px;

}

#icons{
  width:90%;
  height:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5%;
  font-size:15px;
  margin-right:5%;
  background:red;
}

#icons i{
background:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
height:100%;
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="main">
<div id="pic">
</div>
<div id="bio">
<div id="avatar">
  <img style="vertical-align:middle"     src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <span style="">keVin#1234</span>
</div>
<div id="icons">
<i class="fab fa-accusoft"> </i>
  <i class="fab fa-accusoft"> </i>
  <i class="fab fa-accusoft"> </i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify  `#icons i` by adding `line-height:30px`

```
 #icons i {
        background: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
```